# Не корректно работает фиксация шапки при прокрутке страницы

Tags: angular

Такая ситуация,необходимо зафиксировать блоки `blockSearch` (строка поиска), `breadcrumb` при прокрутке страницы. Они расположены ниже, чем шапка высотой 133. По логике, если значения скролла больше 133 - то фиксируем (добавляем класс со стилями), иначе удаляем. Вроде бы все просто.

Контент находящийся ниже изменяется.

Проблема в следующем:
Если скроллить без ввода в строку поиска, то все работает хорошо. 
После ввода же в строке поиска происходит фильтрация выводимого списка и при раскрытом полностью окне все работает хорошо. Но при уменьшенной высоте окна при попытке проскроллить на значения большие 133 ничего не работает. А именно: например значение скролла 134, после чего мы переходим по условию `if (scrollValue > 133)` и далее мы уже получаем другое значение скролла внутри (конкретно - число меньше, чем 133). При попытке переопределить, значение скролла не изменяется.

В итоге происходит некое зацикливание. Так как значения скролла внутри блока, выполняемого по условию не такие, как при выполнении самого условия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
console.log('add before: ', $(document).scrollTop());
$(document).scrollTop(scrollValue);
console.log('add after: ', $(document).scrollTop());


addClassToElement(element, nameClass) {
   element.addClass(nameClass);
}

removeClassToElement(element, nameClass) {
   element.removeClass(nameClass);
}

fixedSearchPanel() {
  let resizeEvent = fromEvent(window, 'resize');
  let scrollEvent = fromEvent(document, 'scroll');

  scrollEvent
    .flatMap(() => {
      let blockSearch = $('.search-region');
      let breadcrumb = $('app-breadcrumb');
      let tabGroup = $('.mat-list');

      let scrollValue = $(document).scrollTop();
      if (scrollValue > 133) {
        let width = tabGroup.width();

        if (!this.isFixedPanel) {
          this.addClassToElement(blockSearch, 'styles_fixed');
          this.addClassToElement(blockSearch, 'search_fixed');
          this.addClassToElement(breadcrumb, 'styles_fixed');
          this.addClassToElement(breadcrumb, 'breadcrumbs_fixed');
          blockSearch.width(width);
          breadcrumb.width(width);

          console.log('scrollValue add: ', scrollValue);

          console.log('add before: ', $(document).scrollTop());
          $(document).scrollTop(scrollValue);
          console.log('add after: ', $(document).scrollTop());

          this.isFixedPanel = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (this.isFixedPanel) {
          this.removeClassToElement(blockSearch, 'styles_fixed');
          this.removeClassToElement(blockSearch, 'search_fixed');
          this.removeClassToElement(breadcrumb, 'styles_fixed');
          this.removeClassToElement(breadcrumb, 'breadcrumbs_fixed');

          this.isFixedPanel = false;
        }
      }
      return resizeEvent;
    })
    .subscribe(() => {
      let blockSearch = $('.search-region');
      let breadcrumb = $('app-breadcrumb');
      let tabGroup = $('.mat-list');

      setTimeout(() => {
        let width = tabGroup.width();
        blockSearch.width(width);
        breadcrumb.width(width);
      });
    });
 }

.styles_fixed{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 background: white;
 }

.breadcrumbs_fixed{
 padding-top: 10px;
 top: 0;
 }

.search_fixed{
 top: 36px;
 }
```

Тут все хорошо. Без ввода и скролла:
[image]

Тоже все хорошо. Без ввода. НО скроллим
[image]

Тоже все хорошо. Вводим. НО НЕ скроллим
[image]

Все плохо. После ввода скроллим до значения 134 после которого происходит зацикливание.
[image]

Comment: Добавьте к своему вопросу скрин макета

Comment: Однако такое происходит не всегда, а только при определенной высоте
Если уменьшить высоту окна - все работает корректно

Comment: Те какой есть интервал по середине. Если до значения 133 - не фиксируется. От этого значения до какого то  - не работает. И далее - все хорошо как и без ввода